# Open a custom url when clicking on a web push notification

Tags: javascript, notifications, web-push

I am implementing the [Webpush ruby gem](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) to send push notifications to users of my website.

Server code:

```
  Webpush.payload_send({
      message: notification.message,
      url: notification.url,  # I can't figure out how to access this key
      id: notification.id,    # or this key from the service worker
      endpoint: endpoint,
      p256dh: p256dh_key,
      vapid: vapid_keys,
      ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
      auth: auth_key,
    })
```

I have a service worker set up on the client side to show the notification and make it clickable.

```
self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  var title = (event.data && event.data.text()) || "New Message";

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: "New push notification",
      icon: "/images/logo@2x.png",
      tag:  "push-notification-tag",
      data: {
        url: event.data.url, // This is returning null
        id: event.data.id // And this is returning null
      }
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.data.url + "?notification_id=" + event.data.id)
  );
})
```

It is all working fine, except the custom keys (`url`, `id`) that I am passing through are not accessible from within the service worker.

Does anyone know how to pass custom data through the WebPush gem?

Comment: im not an expert in this, but i would do: message: JSON.stringify(notification) on the server, and JSON.parse on the client...

Comment: @Jonasw - I ended up going with your solution. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [Webpush (with a payload) documentation](https://github.com/zaru/webpush#with-a-payload), it seems that you should put all your data into the message, using the `JSON.stringify()` method, and retrieve it in the service worker with `JSON.parse()`.

Server:

```
Webpush.payload_send({
  message:JSON.stringify({
    message: notification.message,
    url: notification.url,
    id: notification.id,
  }),
  endpoint: endpoint,
  p256dh: p256dh_key,
  vapid: vapid_keys,
  ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
  auth: auth_key,
})
```

Client:

```
 event.waitUntil(
   self.registration.showNotification(title, {
   body: "New push notification",
   icon: "/images/logo@2x.png",
   tag:  "push-notification-tag",
   data: {
     url: JSON.parse(event.message).url
   }
})
```

Answer (score 21):

Custom data comes in **event.notification** object not in **event** directly(in **notificationclick**). So if you want to fetch the custom data variable in notificationclick function, then you should do it like this :)

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url + "?notification_id=" + event.notification.data.id)
  );
})
```

Comment: The problem was receiving the data from the push event, not from the click event. But you are correct, that was another bug that I ended up needing to fix.

Comment: @BananaNeil can you please mention how did you fix this "The problem was receiving the data from the push event, not from the click event." because i am also not able to send data from the server side to the client side...

Comment: @usama Take a look at the accepted answer, it has the server/client code

Answer (score 3):

For [Webpush Ruby Gem](https://github.com/zaru/webpush), with some modifications, here's what worked for me:

```
Webpush.payload_send(
  endpoint: user.push_subscription.endpoint,
  message: {
    message: "A new service request is created",
    id: service_request.request_number,
    url: "https://google.com/"
  }.to_json,
  p256dh: user.push_subscription.key,
  auth: user.push_subscription.auth_key,
  ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
  vapid: {
    subject: 'A Push Notification',
    public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
    private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
  }
)
```

Where:

- `user.push_subscription.endpoint` is a method defined in `PushSubscription` model to return the endpoint
- `user.push_subscription.key, user.push_subscription.auth_key` are again methods defined in the same model

Inside `/serviceworker.js.erb`

```
self.addEventListener("push", (event) => {
  let response = event.data && event.data.text();
  let title = JSON.parse(response).message;
  let body = JSON.parse(response).id;
  let icon = '/assets/logo-blue-120x120.jpg';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, { body, icon, data: { url: JSON.parse(response).url } })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url)
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your Angular project inside the node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received. event:%s', event);
            event.notification.close();
            if (clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
                event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
            }
        });
```

You can enter the above code where you can find this line inside the file

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => ..
```

And you have to build the dist again for this to work. And in backend you would need to use this format:

```
{"notification":{"body":"This is a message.","title":"PUSH MESSAGE","vibrate":[300,100,400,100,400,100,400],"icon":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/34/AlthepalHappyface.svg/256px-AlthepalHappyface.svg.png","tag":"push demo","requireInteraction":true,"renotify":true,"data":{"url":"https://maps.google.com"}}}
```

Inside the url you can enter your url and on clicking notification your push notification will open the given link and focus it in the browser